# Re-using the same encoder/decoder for the same struct type in Go without creating a new one

Tags: go

I was looking for the quickest/efficient way to store Structs of data to persist on the filesystem. I came across the [gob module](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/gob) which allows encoders and decoders to be set up for structs to convert to []byte (binary) that can be stored.

This was relatively easy - here's a decoding example:

```
// Per item get request
// binary = []byte for the encoded binary from database
// target = struct receiving what's being decoded
func Get(path string, target *SomeType) {
    binary = someFunctionToGetBinaryFromSomeDB(path)
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(binary))
    dec.Decode(target)
}
```

However, when I benchmarked this against JSON encoder/decoder, I found it to be almost twice as slow. This was especially noticeable when I created a loop to retrieve all structs. Upon further research, I learned that creating a NEW decoder every time is really expensive. 5000 or so decoders are re-created.

```
// Imagine 5000 items in total
func GetAll(target *[]SomeType{}) {
    results = getAllBinaryStructsFromSomeDB()
    for results.next() {
        binary = results.getBinary()
        // Making a new decoder 5000 times
        dec := gob.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(binary))
        var target someType
        dec.Decode(target)
        // ... append target to []SomeType{}
    }
}
```

I'm stuck here trying to figure out how I can *recycle* (reduce reuse recycle!) a decoder for list retrieval. Understanding that the decoder takes an io.Reader, I was thinking it would be possible to 'reset' the io.Reader and use the same reader at the same address for a *new* struct retrieval, while still using the same decoder. I'm not sure how to go about doing that and I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas to shed some light. What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
// Imagine 5000 items in total
func GetAll(target *[]SomeType{}) {
    // Set up some kind of recyclable reader
    var binary []byte
    reader := bytes.NewReader(binary)

    // Make decoder based on that reader
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(reader)

    results = getAllBinaryStructsFromSomeDB()
    for results.next() {
        // Insert some kind of binary / decoder reset
        // Then do something like:
        reader.WriteTo(results.nextBinary())

        var target someType
        dec.Decode(target) // except of course this won't work

        // ... append target to []SomeType{}
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you should https://go.dev/blog/pprof profile that code - never assume you know where your cycles are being spent without profiling.  always verify your hunches with data.

Answer (score 2):

The encoder and decoder are designed to work with streams of values. The encoder writes information describing a Go type to the stream once before transmitting the first value of the type. The decoder retains received type information for decoding subsequent values.

The type information written by the encoder is dependent on the order that the encoder encounters unique types, the order of fields in structs and more. To make sense of the stream, a decoder must read the complete stream written by a single encoder.

It is not possible to recycle decoders because of the way that type information is transmitted.

To make this more concrete, the following does not work:

```
 var v1, v2 Type

 var buf bytes.Buffer
 gob.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(v1)
 gob.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(v2)

 var v3, v4 Type
 d := gob.NewDecoder(&buf)
 d.Decode(&v3)
 d.Decode(&v4)
```

Each call to Encode writes information about `Type` to the buffer.  The second call to Decode fails because a duplicate type is received.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "The information describing a type is written once to the stream by the encoder and retained by the decoder. "... Wouldn't it be possible to make the iterations of the database output as a stream? Which can then be read like a stream by the decoder? Or are you saying that you can only write *one* struct (which I think is what I'm not quite clear on by the line you wrote)?

Comment: Much clearer thanks Gopher! :)

Answer (score 2):

> I was looking for the quickest/efficient way to store Structs of data to persist on the filesystem

Instead of serializing your structs, represent your data primarily in a pre-made data store that fits your usage well. Then model that data in your Go code.

This may seem like the hard way or the long way to store data, but it will solve your performance problem by intelligently indexing your data and allowing filtering to be done without a lot of filesystem access.

> I was looking for ... data to persist.

Let's start there as a problem statement.

> gob module allows encoders and decoders to be set up for structs to convert to []byte (binary) that can be stored.
> However, ... I found it to be ... slow.

It would be.  You'd have to go out of your way to make data storage any slower.  Every object you instantiate from your storage will have to come from a filesystem read.  The operating system will cache these small files well, but you'll still be reading the data every time.

Every change will require rewriting all the data, or cleverly determining *which* data to write to disk.  Recall that there is no "insert between" operation for files; you'll be rewriting all bytes after to add bytes in the middle of a file.

You could do this concurrently, of course, and goroutines handle a bunch of async work like filesystem reads very well.  But now you've got to start thinking about locking.

My point is, for the cost of trying to serialize your structures you can better describe your data at the persistent layer, and solve problems you're not even working on yet.

SQL is a pretty obvious choice, since you can make it work with sqlite as well as other sql servers that scale well; I hear mongodb is easy to wrangle these days, and depending on what you're doing with the data, redis has a number of attractive list, set and k/v operations that can easily be made atomic and consistent.

Comment: Thanks for your response! What you're describing is actually what I'm trying to move away from ironically. I'm trying to make a very lightweight program, so big databases (mongodb, mysql, etc) are out of the question. Currently I am using SQLite, but I realized the enormous overhead of SQL compilation, plus the amount of boilerplate it takes to define tables and all that stuff, iterating through rows, etc. I'm using BadgerDB as K/V storage, and what I'm doing right now is already 5x faster than SQLite (including pre-compiled queries), and 5x less code per struct. But I know it can be faster!

Comment: I just felt that the overhead of SQL is really not needed. All I'm doing is select, delete, update. I have about two SQL joins in my whole application, and quite frankly they're kind of unnecessary. I also wouldn't need to do them at all if I could store unstructured data like I can do with maps in a struct (which I can anyway by encoding them into a BLOB but then it would be just *extra* overhead on top of SQL). It just makes way more sense to cut out the middle man and save the struct as a GOB in a fast KV storage like Badger

Comment: @Pete Yup, storing structure values as a blob is more than adequate for many applications.  The choice between MongoDB, Redis, the filesystem or some other K/V store is dependent on requirements outside the scope of your question. You should also consider message pack, JSON or BSON encodings.

Comment: If you're the only reader of the data, it might be easy to identify when it's changing.  Load it on startup, read it from memory, and when it changes, update storage.   That should be plenty fast, unless the data is changing very quickly.